# How to export Astrid tasks into csv now that website is closed?

Tags: astrid

I was a little behind when the Astrid website was closed down because I only used the Android app and not the web app. I saw that the devs provided an export functionality to the web app, but I cannot find it in the Android app, and I could not find any clue on the web on how to do that.

Is there a way to extract my Astrid tasks now that the web app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked on the whole web and could not find any way. So I tried to use the same method that I have recently seen applied to [a similar problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92756/56057): assume that the database is stored in a common format (like SQL) and is accessible in the `data/data` folder of the root partition (equivalent of Windows's Program Files).

This is what I did, and it worked. Here are the steps:

1- Use a rooted explorer like [Total Commander for Android](http://www.ghisler.com/android.htm) and explore in the root partition the folder `/data/data/com.timsu.astrid/databases`.

2- Open your rooted explorer and copy the file `database` (there's no extension) to your SD card so that we can extract it and copy to the computer.

3- Copy via USB or your BlueStacks emulator the `databases` file onto your computer, and open it using a SQLite browser like [this one](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

4- Now you should be able to see the tables structures and contents. The interesting stuff are in the `tasks` and `metadata` tables (the latter contains tags and notes).

5- Execute the following SQL statement to neatly format the pertinent data:

```
SELECT date(t.created / 1000,'unixepoch') as date_created,date(t.modified / 1000,'unixepoch') as date_modified,m2.value as tags, t.title as title,m.value as comment
FROM tasks as t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT task, GROUP_CONCAT(value,' ;; ') as value FROM metadata WHERE key = 'note' GROUP BY task ORDER BY created) as m ON t._id = m.task
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT task, GROUP_CONCAT(value, ';') as value FROM metadata WHERE key = 'tags-tag' GROUP BY task) as m2 ON t._id = m2.task
GROUP BY t._id ORDER BY t._id
```

6- Export the result into the file format you want, like .csv.

It's interesting to note that this method is quite generic and may also work for other Android apps.