# 2016 Colornote saving manual backup in .doc format

Tags: backup, colornote

I saw in [Import data from ColorNote app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35207/44325) that I could open the `colornote.db` file that was stored on `/data/data/com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note/databases/` with a DB SQLite browser. I think it must be outdated because there is no databases folder but files and cache folders instead.

Therefore, I did a manual backup and I saw that the backup file was given a name of `(whatever).doc` extension. And when I opened that `.doc` file, I saw strange characters.

How can I open that file correctly?

Comment: Re: the linked post, I don't think it's outdated, but it's on the root folder and can only be accessed if the device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a manual backup from your notes the app prompts a *master password* to protect and **encrypt** your backed up notes.

So that's why you see weird characters in that `.doc` file.

If you want to open it on your computer you have to find out which kind of encryption was used on it and with that master password you can decrypt it.

**EDIT**: Colornote uses AES-128 encryption.

Comment: ": Notes will be encrypted before uploading using the AES standard" 

How can I open that?

Comment: Search an AES decrypt method.

Comment: I'm trying a few of them online but they're giving me wrong output although the password is correct...

Comment: I'm currently trying with Cryptool which seems a good one with 128 and 256 encryption. In the input I put the equivalent of my password in hexadecimal characters and then leave the zeros that are given by default on the right side. But the output is still not text! This is a nightmare how can it be so difficult?

Comment: The point is that in encryption to make it hard to decrypt the secured data.

Comment: @BálintBabics Yes, but not when one has the key... Wild guess regarding OP's troubles getting decryption to work: You are trying to convert your password manually into a 128-bit key, but that key is perhaps supposed to be generated from some clever hash function?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that .doc and .backup files are identical to ColorNote. The current version's import function stupidly will not allow you to choose .doc files to import as a backup. Renaming my backup from .doc to .backup allowed me to successfully import an autosave, which as far as I can tell do not have master passwords associated with them.