# How do I export all Colornote to text?

Tags: colornote

How can I export my notes from Colornote to a text file? My notes are very valuable to me and I want a way to keep them which is independent of Colornote.

This is the link to the App: [ColorNote Notepad Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note&gl=GB)

Comment: Consider this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92756

Answer (score 2):

- Select the note you want to export.
- Press the 3-dot, then select Send.
- Select Drive, select the folder where the note must be saved, click on Save. The note will be saved and you will be able to open it as a text file even if it does not have a txt extension.

You must repeat the process for each file as the app does not allow to send a batch of notes.